# FragmentA (pressing next)--> Activity(automatically starts)--> FragmentB

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following scenario:

FragmentA (pressing next)--> Activity(automatically starts)--> FragmentB.

Because of the Android library that I'm currently using, I must start my fragmentB automatically through an activity.

I tried `android:noHistory="true"` on my activity but I still have the following unwanted behavior:

**Current behavior:** When pressing back button on FragmentB, I'm going to my activity, then when I press it again I go to FragmentA.

My activity only has a toolbar and nothing else.

I would like to go back to FragmentA when pressing the back button on FragmentB

Comment: did you try getActivity().finish()

Comment: @Linxy Yeah tried that already and it did WORK but the animation is awful :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getActivity().finish() ;
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

will kill the activity along with the fragment and make the transition instant.

Comment: Great, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the fragment to the backstack while performing the FragmentTransaction.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                       .add(detailFragment, "detail")
                       .addToBackStack()  // Add this transaction to the backstack
                       .commit();
```

when using fragments in your app, individual FragmentTransaction objects may represent context changes which can cause loosing the previous fragments and required to be added to the back stack while performing FragmentTransaction. To understand the back navigation in android in better way and detailed explanation you can refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did try this logic before, but clicking on the back button is bringing me back to the activity layout which is only a toolbar and an empty body. My fragment is residing inside's the layout of my activity and the back button is on the toolbar.